# How to copy filename up to specific characters (and add the copied text to the top of the same file)

Tags: bash, macos, filenames

I'm updating a bash script (for Mac) that I have not looked at in a while and I want to copy the characters of a filename up to __ (two underscores). What I have currently grabs the first 6 characters, and pastes it fine, but I'm not sure how to change it to copy everything up to the first two underscores (not _ or a single underscore).

```
#This copies the first 6 characters of the FILENAME 
#and adds it to the top of the same file
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./*.txt
do
    text="${filename:2:6}"
    echo $text | cat - $filename > temp && mv temp $filename;
done;
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: .bat is not an OSX script it is Windows scripting

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
text=$(sed 's/__.*/__/' <<< "$filename")
```

- `__.*` matches the first two underscores and the following characters in the $filename
- Then the `s` command replaces the above substring with two underscores.

BTW please remember to enclose variable names `$text` and `$filename` with double quotes in the subsequent line.

Comment: Excellent - thank you! With a tiny tweak it worked perfectly for me. I changed the second "__" ref. to blank to remove it and added :2 after "filename" there to trim "./" it was adding in the result... probably a path name thing. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bash which offers a special substitution `%%` for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *.txt
do
    text="${filename%%__*}"     # Remove "__" and anything that follows
    echo $text | cat - $filename > temp && mv temp $filename;
done
```

(please note that I replaced `./*.txt` with `*.txt` in your script)